# Adjusting reCAPTCHA `data-size` on smaller devices

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I'm trying to work out some mobile formatting for my site and everything seems to be working except for the reCAPTCHA box.

I did some research and learned that adjusting the width is not possible and adding `transform: scale(SPECIFIC SCALE);` works, but doesn't change the padding on the sides the way I would like them to.

I landed on changing the `data-size` attribute to either `normal` or `compact` depending on if you are large or small screen.

Doing this seemed to work until I released that reCAPTCHA doesn't re-render the reCAPTCHA box when an attribute is added/changed.

**TLDR;** How do I force a re-render of the reCAPTCHA box when I set the `data-size` attribute to either `normal` or `compact` in the javscript below? Or let me know if you have another solution that might work better!

I implemented the following javscript code:

HTML

```html
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeWllEnAAAAALdycq7AIRWIf-CS_JOwcwHZvzLF"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const recaptchaElement = document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha');
    
    function updateRecaptchaSize() {
        if(window.innerWidth <= 530) {
            recaptchaElement.setAttribute('data-size','compact');
        } else {
            recaptchaElement.setAttribute('data-size','normal');
        }
    }

    // calling the function on page load
    updateRecaptchaSize();

    // triggers anytime the window size is changed
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateRecaptchaSize);
});
```

According to the inspector, the attributes are changing, this just doesn't actually update the reCAPTCHA box because of what I stated above.